# PowerShell - How to use 'Start-Process' and rename the newly launched windowtitle

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use the PowerShell (version 2) `Start-Process` and rename the newly launched window title. I have the following snippet of code that works fine, it launches a new PowerShell window and tails logs (`$c` contains the log file to tail):-

```powershell
Start-Process powershell.exe -Argument "Get-Content", $c, "-wait"
```

I am not sure how to include the following so that the newly launched window title can be changed.

```powershell
$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = 'New window title rename example text'
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A "dirty" solution would be:

```
start-process powershell.exe -argument "`$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = 'New window title rename example text'; get-content -Path $c -wait"
```

I would recommend creating a script for you commands and use parameters for input.

Untitled2.ps1

```
param($c)
$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = 'New window title rename example text'
Get-Content -Path $c -Wait
```

Script

```
$script = Get-Item ".\Desktop\Untitled2.ps1"
$c = Get-Item ".\Desktop\t.txt"
Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-File $($script.FullName) -c $($c.FullName)"
```

Comment: Thank you so very much, that worked. I used your first recommendation and that did the trick.

Answer (score 7):

A cleaner powershell solution, especially if you're going to run further commands at the time you spawn the process, might be like this.

```
$StartInfo = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$StartInfo.FileName = "$pshome\powershell.exe"
$StartInfo.Arguments = "-NoExit -Command `$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle=`'Your Title Here`'"
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($StartInfo)
```

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted, constructive feedback welcomed!

Comment: I think your solution is slightly lacking, in that it does not pass along the original command (Get-Content) as one of the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

if anyone need a easy way ,you can try this in powershell:

```
 cmd.exe /c "start  ""my app"" powershell.exe -NoExit -Command  ""dotnet myapp"""
```

it also means this command in cmd:

```
start "myapp" powershell.exe -NoExit -Command "dotnet myapp"
```